# How to use context with hooks for authentication?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm trying to use `context` for handling pieces of authentication in my app. I was running into issues because I was trying to call `useContext` outside of my `Context.Provider`, so I moved the logic to a child component of the provider.

Now I'm getting an error message `TypeError: Object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))` where I'm calling `useContext` in the child component. Is the issue really with getting the values from the context or something else?

In `app.js`

```
import AuthContextProvider from "./components/context/authContext";
import RegisterRoutes from "./components/routing/registerRoutes";

function App() {
   return (
      <AuthContextProvider>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/register"
            render={(props) => (
              <RegisterRoutes {...props} />
            )}
          />
      </AuthContextProvider>
   )
}
```

In my `authContext.js`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, createContext } from "react";

export const AuthContext = createContext();

const AuthContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const setAuth = (boolean) => {
    setIsAuthenticated(boolean);
  };

//Auth API logic here//
  const apiOptions = {
    url: "users/is-verified",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      token: localStorage.token,
    },
  };

  async function isAuth() {
    axios(apiOptions)
      .then((response) => {
        const resData = response.data;
        resData === true ? setIsAuthenticated(true) : setIsAuthenticated(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response);
      });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    isAuth();
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={[isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated, setAuth]}
    >
      {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AuthContextProvider;
```

In my `registerRoutes.js`

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import Register from "../pages/register";
import AuthContext from "../context/authContext";

function RegisterRoutes(props) {
  const [isAuthenticated, setAuth] = useContext(AuthContext);

  return !isAuthenticated ? (
    <Register {...props} setAuth={setAuth} />
  ) : (
    <Redirect to="/login" />
  );
}

export default RegisterRoutes;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, the `Context.Provider` in `authContext.js` value is not iterable:

```
<AuthContext.Provider value={[isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated, setAuth]}>
```

The value passed to the provider needs to be an iterable value, in this case, a valid JSON object, instead of the array that you have provided. so, we change it to:

```
<AuthContext.Provider value={{isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated, setAuth}}>
```

Then you change the reference in `registerRoutes.js` to correctly consume the new structure:

```
const [isAuthenticated, setAuth] = useContext(AuthContext);
```

becomes

```
const { isAuthenticated, setAuth } = useContext(AuthContext);
```

Voila! Your Context.Provider value is iterable and you can consume it in your application.

Comment: That makes sense, but now I'm getting the error `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'isAuthenticated' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined` from `registerRoutes.js`. I though by having `useState(false)` in its definition that it had `false` as a default value?

Comment: Did you update `const [isAuthenticated, setAuth] = useContext(AuthContext);` to `const { isAuthenticated, setAuth } = useContext(AuthContext);` ?

Comment: Yeah, I did. I'm importing `AuthContext` to that file. Is there something I need to do with it before including it in `useContext`?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you. My solution for accessing data in the context is creating a custom hook.

```js
//localState.js

import { createContext, useState, useContext } from 'react'

const LocalStateContext = createContext()

const LocalStateProvider = LocalStateContext.Provider

function LocalState({children}) {
  const [someState, setSomeState] = useState('')
  const defaultValues = {
    someState, setSomeState
  }
  
  return <LocalStateProvider value={defaultValues}>
            {children}
         </LocalStateProvider>
}

function useLocalState() {
  const all = useContext(LocalStateContext)
  return all
}

export {LocalState, LocalStateContext, useLocalState}
```

With this code you can wrap your whole app in the LocalState component and access context values by using the new useLocalState hook. For example

```js
import { useLocalState} from './localstate'

const SomeComponent = () => {
  const { someState } = useLocalState()
  
  return (
    ///...whatever you want
  )
}

export default SomeComponent
```

I think your issue may be that you have put your default values in an array inside of the value object.

Comment: I like this approach, however after changing my default values to be inside of an object, I get the error `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'isAuthenticated' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined.`

Comment: @userNick could you share the code? If you are setting state somewhere then using that value in another component in the same render you may run into the issue that useState is async and thats why it is undefined.

Comment: state is getting set in an api call within `authContext.js`. I just updated the original post to include that code.